# Can't get correct current islamic date

Tags: java, jodatime

i am using joda time to get current islamic date in **Saudi Arabia** as in their website:

```
DateTime dtISO = new DateTime(2014, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime dtIslamic = dtISO.withChronology(IslamicChronology.getInstance());
```

above prints the day less than the actual day, it prints that today is 7 but actual is 8.
please advise.

**UPDATE:**

i even tried it with timezone as follows:

```
DateTimeZone SAUDI_ARABIA = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Riyadh");
DateTime dtISO = new DateTime(2014, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime dtIslamic = dtISO.withChronology(IslamicChronology.getInstance(SAUDI_ARABIA));
```

but it gives same result.

Comment: Have you considered your timezone?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, yes and updated question with code, it gives same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I have experimented with JodaTime's "leap-year-pattern". All four defined patterns yield the same result, namely the date "Hijrah 1435-03-07". Here my test code:

```
DateTime dtISO = new DateTime(2014, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTimeZone tzSAUDI_ARABIA = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Riyadh");
DateTime dtIslamic = 
  dtISO.withChronology(
    IslamicChronology.getInstance(
      tzSAUDI_ARABIA, 
      IslamicChronology.LEAP_YEAR_15_BASED));
System.out.println(dtIslamic);
```

According to the website islamicfinder.org the date should indeed be:

> Thursday 8 Raby` al-awal 1435 A.H.

Or see: http://www.ummulqura.org.sa/

We have to memorize here that Joda Time only supports islamic calendar based on an algorithmic calculation using a special leap year pattern. All in all I know of 8 such patterns. Joda Time defines four of them. What Joda Time does not support is the official calendar of Saudi-Arabia, namely Umalqura calendar which is a sighting based calendar. So as summary we can say: Using Joda Time is no option for Saudi-Arabia. What to do now?

One option is using `com.ibm.icu.util.IslamicCalendar` as @PopoFibo has mentioned. The other option would be currently waiting for Java 8 which contains Umalqura calendar which is not necessary the same as the IBM version. In detail: While the IBM version is still based on calculations (either "astronomical" (not really) or "civil") the class `java.time.chrono.HijrahDate` uses a background lookup table with data given by saudi-arabian agency KACST. I would trust this version far more than the IBM version because for other dates IBM (here its library ICU4J) is not necessarily correct. So in Java 8 you could use:

```
HijrahDate hdate = 
  HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(LocalDate.of(2014, Month.JANUARY, 9));
System.out.println(hdate); // Output: "Hijrah-umalqura AH 1435-03-08"
```

Comment: That's a very detailed explanation, very helpful! These changes in Java 8 part of JSR 310?

Comment: @Meno Hochschild, thanks for very detailed explanation, but the com.ibm.icu.util.IslamicCalendar has an issue with old dates, see my above comments.

Comment: @PopoFibo Yes the new Java 8 code I presented is part of JSR 310.

Comment: @MahmoudS Well, I have no ICU4J-library available and therefore not tested for old dates, but I am also not astonished because its implementation does not cover the Umalqura calendar. If you cannot wait until Java 8 is out you might use Microsoft .NET which offers such a calendar, too, else you are out of luck, sorry. Or: In the meantime you just use ICU4J (if you can tolerate errors for old dates) and then migrate to Java 8 - I know it is work.

Comment: Better code for the last example would be HijrahDate.from(LocalDate.of(2014, Month.JANUARY, 9))

Comment: @JodaStephen You are right, I had also noticed it some days later. Many ways to write a solution. My personal feeling is there are too many methods per class in average which can cause users loosing the overview.

Comment: When I run the provided code sample, I get the wrong date: 1435-03-07T08:00:00.000+03:00

Answer (score 3):

Joda doesn't seem to have the provision to change civil and astronomical epochs. As I see from the reference, according to civil epoch it's 7th today and 8th per astronomical.

`com.ibm.icu.util.IslamicCalendar` might do this job for you; it has an explicit boolean for civil epoch which can be set to `false`

```
IslamicCalendar calendar = new IslamicCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Riyadh"));
calendar.setCivil(false);
System.out.println(calendar.getDateTimeFormat(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.MEDIUM, new Locale("en")).format(new Date()));
```

**Output:**

> 3/8/35 9:50:30 PM

If I change the DateFormat to `MEDIUM`, `MEDIUM` it changes the output:

```
System.out.println(calendar.getDateTimeFormat(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, new Locale("en")).format(new Date()));
```

**Changed Output:**

> Rabi? I 8, 1435 9:51:58 PM

I don't have much experience with the util hence cannot accurately interpret the above results but hope the above would help your cause.

Needless to say `setCivil(true)` sets the date to 7th.

Comment: this method can get current islamic date correct, but it has big issue with get islamic date for old date for example try following code: `Calendar dateCal = Calendar.getInstance(); dateCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); dateCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7); dateCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011); IslamicCalendar calendar = new IslamicCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Riyadh")); calendar.setCivil(false); System.out.println(calendar.getDateTimeFormat(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.MEDIUM, new Locale("en")).format(dateCal.getTime()));` it should print 8/30/32 9:50:30 PM

Comment: 7 is august, and the above date 1 august 2011 is equivalent to 30/8/1432 according to um al qura calendar but it gives 9/2/1432

Comment: @MahmoudS I see, but with `setCivil(true)` I get `9/1/32 6:28:16 AM` which is what I get 9/1/32 [here](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/islam/ummalqura_converter.htm) and [here](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/islam/ummalqura_converter.htm). Don't know about the validity of these references though!

Comment: ,ok setting date to 31 jul in above references gives result 30-8 which with above code produces 29-8 and with that seems that this api conversion is not 100% correct.

Comment: @MahmoudS yep, I see it now - skips 30/8 when setCivil is flipped

Comment: This is the best solution available online to get the most accurate islamic date available :) Thank you for sharing

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

Java 8 comes with brilliant feature, the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

These new classes support more than one calandar, (Hijrah, Japanese, Minguo, Thai Buddhist), so every country or region could choose their specific calander, this example is good as start point

```
package javafx_datepicker;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.chrono.Chronology;
import java.time.chrono.HijrahChronology;
import java.time.chrono.IsoChronology;
import java.time.chrono.JapaneseChronology;
import java.time.chrono.MinguoChronology;
import java.time.chrono.ThaiBuddhistChronology;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFX_DatePicker extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    //New DataPicker init at now
    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    datePicker.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            LocalDate date = datePicker.getValue();
            System.err.println("Selected date: " + date);
        }

    });

    //reload datePicker at now
    Button btnNow = new Button("Now");
    btnNow.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        }

    });

    final ToggleGroup groupChronology = new ToggleGroup();
    RadioButton optDefault = new RadioButton("default");
    optDefault.setToggleGroup(groupChronology);
    optDefault.setSelected(true);
    optDefault.setUserData(null);

    RadioButton optHijrah = new RadioButton("HijrahChronology");
    optHijrah.setToggleGroup(groupChronology);
    optHijrah.setUserData(HijrahChronology.INSTANCE);

    RadioButton optIso = new RadioButton("IsoChronology");
    optIso.setToggleGroup(groupChronology);
    optIso.setUserData(IsoChronology.INSTANCE);

    RadioButton optJapanese = new RadioButton("JapaneseChronology");
    optJapanese.setToggleGroup(groupChronology);
    optJapanese.setUserData(JapaneseChronology.INSTANCE);

    RadioButton optMinguo = new RadioButton("MinguoChronology");
    optMinguo.setToggleGroup(groupChronology);
    optMinguo.setUserData(MinguoChronology.INSTANCE);

    RadioButton optThaiBuddhist = new RadioButton("ThaiBuddhistChronology");
    optThaiBuddhist.setToggleGroup(groupChronology);
    optThaiBuddhist.setUserData(ThaiBuddhistChronology.INSTANCE);

    groupChronology.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>(){

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observable, 
                Toggle oldValue, Toggle newValue) {
            if (groupChronology.getSelectedToggle() != null) {
                datePicker.setChronology(
                        (Chronology)groupChronology.getSelectedToggle().getUserData());

            }else{
                datePicker.setChronology(null);
            }
        }
    });

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(optDefault, 
            optHijrah, optIso, optJapanese, optMinguo, optThaiBuddhist,
            btnNow, datePicker);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(vBox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

reference to [JavaFX with Chronologie](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2014/08/datapickersetchronology-set-calendar.html), the only requirement to run the code is java 8

Good luck