# Test a date within a day intervall range

Tags: java, date

I have a date and a number and want to check if this date and this number occurs in a list of other dates within:

- `+-20` date intervall with the same number

so for example `1, 1.1.2013` and `1,3.1.2013` should reuturn false.

I tried to implement the method something like that:

```
private List<EventDate> dayIntervall(List<EventDate> eventList) throws Exception {
    List<EventDate> resultList = new ArrayList<EventDate>();

    for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
        String string = eventList.get(i).getDate();
        Date equalDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMAN).parse(string);
        for (int j = 0; j < eventList.size(); j++) {
            String string1 = eventList.get(i).getDate();
            Date otherDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMAN).parse(string1);
            if (check number of i with number of j && check Date) {
                //do magic
            }
        }

    }

    return resultList;
}
```

The construction of the iteration method is not that hard. What is hard for me is the date intervall checking part. I tried it like that:

```
boolean isWithinRange(Date testDate, Date days) {
           return !(testDate.before(days) || testDate.after(days));
    }
```

However that does not work because days are not takes as days. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: If your date format is `dd.MM.yyyy` and you want to check if two dates are within twenty days of each other, shouldn't you return `true` for `1.1.2013` and `3.1.2013`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is difficult to follow. But given its title, perhaps this will help…

## Span Of Time In Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library provides a trio of classes to represent a span of time: [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_interval.html), [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_period.html), and [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_duration.html).

### Interval

An [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) object has specific endpoints that lie on the timeline of the Universe. A handy `contains` method tells if a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object occurs within those endpoints. The beginning endpoint in inclusive while the last endpoint is exclusive.

### Time Zones

Note that time zones are important, for handling Daylight Saving Time and other anomalies, and for handling start-of-day. Keep in mind that while a java.util.Date seems like it has a time zone but does not, a DateTime truly does know its own time zone.

### Sample Code

Some code off the top of my head (untested)…

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Berlin" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( yourDateGoesHere, timeZone );
Interval interval = new Interval( dateTime.minusDays( 20 ), dateTime.plusDays( 20 ) );
boolean didEventOccurDuringInterval = interval.contains( someOtherDateTime );
```

### Whole Days

If you want whole days, call the [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay%28%29) method to get first moment of the day. In this case, you probably need to add 21 rather than 20 days for the ending point. As I said above, the end point is exclusive. So if you want whole days, you need the first moment *after* the time period you care about. You need the moment after the stroke of midnight. If this does not make sense, see my answers to other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21325595/642706) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20990737/642706).

Note that Joda-Time includes some "midnight"-related methods and classes. Those are no longer recommended by the Joda team. The "withTimeAtStartOfDay" method takes their place.

```
DateTime start = dateTime.minusDays( 20 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime stop = dateTime.plusDays( 21 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay(); // 21, not 20, for whole days.
Interval interval = new Interval( start, stop );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid `java.util.Date` if at all possible. Using the backport of [ThreeTen](http://www.threeten.org/) (the long awaited replacement date/time API coming in JDK8), you can get the number of days between two dates like so:

```
int daysBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    return Math.abs(start.periodUntil(end).getDays());
}
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of dates in between the 2 dates and compare with your `days` parameter. Using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) API it is relatively an easy task: [How do I calculate the difference between two dates?](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#datediff).

Code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);

Date startDate = format.parse("1.1.2013");
Date endDate = format.parse("3.1.2013");

Days d = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(startDate), new DateTime(endDate));
System.out.println(d.getDays());
```

Gives,

```
2
```

This is possible using `Calendar` class as well:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(startDate);
System.out.println(cal.fieldDifference(endDate, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
```

Gives,

```
2
```

This 2 can now be compared to your actual value (20).

Comment: @gdejohn I don't think having a valid alternative is doing any harm here?

Comment: I didn't say it was doing any harm, and I didn't mean for you or anyone to infer that. I was just wondering exactly what I asked. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @gdejohn no worries at all, I was in fact unaware of ThreeTen backport for 7. Though I am aware of JSR-310 capabilities and the vast improvements, discussions which I have been part of for various problems not overcome by joda - like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023907/cant-get-correct-current-islamic-date).

Comment: Beware that the *backport* (to Java 7) of ThreeTen may not be ready for production use – I'm not sure of its status, I'm merely cautioning you to check. The Oracle-backed implementation being bundled with Java 8 is in final testing now. Joda-Time is still alive and worthwhile, useful for projects in Java 7 and earlier. And those projects will continue to run in Java 8. Joda-Time is actively maintained. Eventually Joda-Time will be supplanted by the [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) but that day is some years away.

Comment: @BasilBourque, why would that be years away? JSR-310 is supposed to address design flaws in Joda-Time and should be production-ready in, like, a month when it's made available as part of Java 8.